# restarting a script upon boot in screen/tmux

Tags: systemd, cron, reboot

I have a script that runs in dot net, that works fine when starting it through putty- either in screen or in tmux.

However i have been trying for in total over 8 hours to get it to work with systemd or crontab, but it doesn't seem to work.

When i run it in cron or systemd, the script wont start or work.

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo ""
echo "Running NadekoBot with auto restart and updating to latest build!"
root="/root"
youtube-dl -U

sleep 5s
while :; do cd "$root/NadekoBot" && dotnet restore && dotnet build --configuration Release && cd "$root/NadekoBot/src/NadekoBot" && dotnet run -c Release && cd "$root" && wget -N https://github.com/Kwoth/NadekoBot-BashScript/raw/1.4/nadeko_installer_latest.sh && bash "$root/nadeko_installer_latest.sh"; sleep 5s; done
echo ""
echo "That didn't work? Please report in #NadekoLog Discord Server."
sleep 3s

cd "$root"
bash "$root/linuxAIO.sh"
echo "Done"

rm "$root/NadekoARU_Latest.sh"
exit
```

Comment: How do you know it didn't start or work?

Comment: because it launches a discord bot, and the bot is not active. When launching it myself through putty remotely- it works and the bot comes online in discord.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, after many hours of trying to figure it out. This works for `nadekobot` at least.
Copy this text into the `systemd` system folder as a `nedekobot.service` file, then don't forget to enable the service file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Nadekobot

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/root/
User=root
Type=forking

ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux new-session -s mc-%i -d '/bin/sh nadeko_start.sh'

ExecStop=/bin/sleep 2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```